# Discriminate between circular and non-circular contours

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there an OpenCV function that can determine if a contour is circular?

- `fitEllipse()` seems to work for any contour (correct me if I am wrong, I did a quick test).
- `isContourConvex()` would'nt even detect my best circles.

I am attempting to detect pizzas (camera is at an angle so the pizza shapes are ellipses). `HoughCircles` works for the pizza's general position but not for the pizza's elliptical shape (it either find circles too small or too large).

```
static void detectPizzas(const Mat& roi)
{
    Mat blur, edges;
    GaussianBlur(roi, blur, Size(3, 3), 0);
    Canny(blur, edges, 200, 275);
    dilate(edges, edges, getStructuringElement(CV_SHAPE_ELLIPSE, { 3, 3 }));

    std::vector<std::vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(edges, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // Following draws ellipses to all contours that aren't even circular. 
    // How can I discriminate between 'circular' contours and non-circular contours?
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) 
    {
        // Doesn't detect any ellipses
        //if (!isContourConvex(contours[i]))
        //  continue;

        RotatedRect r = fitEllipse(contours[i]);

        ellipse(edges, r, { 125 }, 2);
    }

    imshow("edges", edges);
}
```

Sample images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: fitEllipse is ellipse fitting, not ellipse detection, so it will always compute an ellipsse from your contour. To test how good that ellipse fits to your contour you can compute the distance between the fitted ellipse's contour and the original contour, for example with hausdorff-distance. A tools that might help you is the function cv::distanceTransform

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find cost of ellipse in OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121045/find-cost-of-ellipse-in-opencv)