# OpenCV: Fitting a single circle to an image (in Python)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have an image like this:

[image]

I need to fit an ellipse to the dark area (note: must be an ellipse, not a circle). What is the best way to do this in OpenCV? My first step so far has been to apply an adaptive (Otsu) threshold to it, which results in:

[image]

But I'm not sure where to go from there. I'm writing the app in Python, but it's more the algorithm design I'm looking for.

**EDIT based on response/comment:**

OK, so I have already tried the morphology. Based on the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.7/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html), I did a 3-iteration "close" operation on it (dilation, then erosion) to remove the small particles, which results in:

[image]

Then, to expand it back out to closerto the original shape, I did a 3-iteration "open" operation (erosion, then dilation), which results in:

[image]

From here, I did Canny edge detection, which resulted in:

[image]

Now, I used `findContours` on it, but ran into an issue. It found dozens of contours along the edge, each one a short segment along the circumference. Which means, even if I take the maximum size contour, it might only represent 10% of the circumference, which is insufficient to accurately fit an ellipse. This is why the other questions that @Demi-Lune suggested didn't work for me; they all have very clean, sharp edges and `findContours` finds a nice single contour that covers the entire perimiter of each shape, but that doesn't happen for my messier image. So, what's the best way to fit the ellipse from here?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206042/ellipse-detection-in-opencv-python ? or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121045/find-cost-of-ellipse-in-opencv ?

Comment: @Demi-Lune see my edit in the question. Basically, those questions have nice clean shapes with clearly defined edges, and `findContours` finds nice single contours for those; that doesn't work for my messier images.

Comment: Find the minarearect of the black points.. It represents your ellipse

Comment: That would only work if there were no extraneous dots outside the circle, right? That is the case for this particular image, but not universal (some images I process might have the odd dot here and there outside of the circle, even after morphology). Also, if one side of the circle was "flattened" (so it looked more like a 'D'), it wouldn't fit the best ellipse, it would fit one that was smaller.

Comment: #1 correct, #2 the "best" is according to a metric... "least square error" and "has more overlap with the boundary points" produce different results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the object has circle shape, then use `cv2.minEnclosingCircle` is good. Or else, you can use `cv2.fitEllipse` to find the most fitted ellipse around the object. Remember to do find contour with white object in black background.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("1.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)

element = cv2.getStructuringElement(shape=cv2.MORPH_RECT, ksize=(5, 5))

morph_img = thresh.copy()
cv2.morphologyEx(src=thresh, op=cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel=element, dst=morph_img)

contours,_ = cv2.findContours(morph_img,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
sorted_areas = np.sort(areas)

#bounding box (red)
cnt=contours[areas.index(sorted_areas[-1])] #the biggest contour
r = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
cv2.rectangle(img,(r[0],r[1]),(r[0]+r[2],r[1]+r[3]),(0,0,255),2)

#min circle (green)
(x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
center = (int(x),int(y))
radius = int(radius)
cv2.circle(img,center,radius,(0,255,0),2)

#fit ellipse (blue)
ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
cv2.ellipse(img,ellipse,(255,0,0),2)


cv2.imshow("morph_img",morph_img)
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked fairly well. Say I wanted to "Average" the results from the `minBoundingRectangle` (specifically, the ellipse that can be inscribed within it) and the `fitEllipse` functions. How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1):

why don't you do thing like "close" then "open" to clear all the mess.

Raw image :

[image: Raw image]

Otsu :

[image: Otsu]

Close + open ; both with 7x7 kernel ; The binary image is beauty and clean now.

[image: Close + Open]

Only one contour is detect :

[image: One contour]

The ellipse is as : (please not that your image is circle so ellipse should be in circle shape)

[image: Ellipse]

Comment: Thanks @Vu. Now, let's say the binary thresholded, morphed image is solid, but has a "bulge" out the side (a pointy lump sticking out). If I use `fitEllipse` on this, the bulge will affect the fit and make it more oblong, but I need a solution that maximizes the number of points fit, not the least-square. That is, it should match the contour of the shape for as many points possible.

Comment: Don't understand what're you talking about. You should add some picture to clarify your problems